# Magento - Customer Not Logged in After Redirect From External Page

Tags: session, soap, magento

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a customer to stay logged in after I have created a new account. I'm creating them an account and adding products to a cart from an external site, and then sending them to Magento store. What I want to have happen is:

1. A customer goes to a signup page and enters relevant information.
2. They go to a new page where they can choose to add free samples to their cart.
3. After picking samples. their account is created and they are redirected to the Magento store with the samples in their cart.

The problem I'm having is between steps 2 and 3. I create an account using the Magento's SOAP API with the following:

```
$customerInfo = array('firstname' => $custFirstname, 'lastname' => $custLastname, 'email' => $email, 'password_hash' => md5( $new_password ), 'store_id' => 34, 'website_id' => 25,'group_id' => 9);

// Call API method customer.create
$newCustomerId = $client->call( $session, 'customer.create', array( $customerInfo ) );
```

I then return their customer ID, which I pass to another function which actually logs them in and adds products to their cart:

```
public static function _addSamplesToCart($customer_id, $sample_one, $sample_two, $sample_three){
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array("name" => "frontend"));
$customerSession->init("customer_bn_us");
$customerSession->loginById($customer_id);
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProductsByIds($idArray);
$cart->save();
$cart->getCheckoutSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
}
```

These functions are actually called from AJAX post requests, so when I get a successful return value from _addSamplesToCart, I do a simple javascript redirect (window.location ="http://www.myhostname.net/welcome") and it correctly takes me there, but I'm not logged in.

I've been looking around all afternoon and trying a few different things and nothing has worked. I've also tried doing a hidden form submit to /customer/account/loginPost and it still doesn't work. I have verified that it's correctly creating an account in Magento. My only hunch is that I'm doing this with a mix of AJAX and PHP so somehow the cookies or sessions are getting mixed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to login from an hostname different from the one used by the Magento store, it cannot work. You can verify this by checking if a frontend cookie is created after the AJAX call.

I suggest you to create a new controller in Magento that receives the id of the customer just created and executes the code you wrote in your function:

www.myhostname.net/autologin/myaction/13 (where 13 is the id of the customer just created).

Obviously you should add something else to avoid security issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The thing is, I'm not coming from a different hostname. I have a page external from Magento at hostname.net/signup, and the main store is just at hostname.net. I did some digging of the cookies, however, and I found that the session ID returned by the Magento customer session is not the same as the frontend cookie. I'm assuming I need to set the frontend cookie to have the same ID as the customer session, right?

Comment: No, I set the frontend cookie to have the same session ID as the customer session and it still doesn't place me as logged in. Right now I set the cookie just before I return to the AJAX call which redirects me to /welcome. I have verified that it replaces the previous frontend cookie as well.

Comment: Sorry for all the repeat posts, but I've almost got it working. I followed Fabrizio's advice and just started using a login controller. Right now it successfully logs me in, but now I'm stuck at adding products to my cart. I've looked around at the right way to add products, and I'm really sure I'm doing it right. After some digging with Mage::log though, I traced the problem all the way down to the setQty() method of Sales_Model_Quote_Item. There appears to be a problem with this method dispatching an event: `Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_item_qty_set_after', array('item'=>$this))`

Comment: If I throw up a try-catch block when I try to add a product, everything works fine. I logged the exception and this is what I get from Magento: Stock item for Product is not valid. It doesn't make sense that it would still add my products to the cart successfully, though.

Comment: It looks like you are managing the stock in Magento. If you don't need this feature, you can disable it in the admin panel. Otherwise, I suggest to try a for-loop on all your ids ($idArray) and use the function $cart->addProduct($product_id, null); instead of $cart->addProductsByIds($idArray);